# How to change colors of Switch (how to deal with Switch on black backgroud)

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

I am making an app that has black background in all windows and i need to use the `Switch` widget. But the problem is that it does not look good with the black background, when the switch is off half of it can't be seen because it visually merges with the background. Here is a photo: [image]

So how can i change the slider (oval) color? I know i can change the handle (circle) color but that's not what i need as that looks alright.

At worst i can add some white background only for this element, but i would rather not do that because it would look weird, i think.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try add this line to your styles:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">youruncheckedcolor</item>
```